# js undefined function is actually defined, can't see what's missing

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am currently making a ship model for a computer graphics class, and i've hit a serious bump. The debugger returns a message saying the render() function called by both of my handleLoadedTextures() is undefined. I've been at this for hours and I'm sure it's a stupid mistake, but I just can't see it. Everything seems to be in place and I am out of ideas.

The two functions calling a seemingly undefined render():

```js
function handleLoadedTexture(texture) { //From texture-3cubes.js provided example
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  texture.isloaded = true;

  render(); // Call render function when the image has been loaded (to insure the model is displayed)

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function handleLoadedTextureMap(texture) {

  ct++;
  if (ct == 6) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
    var targets = [
      gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
      gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
      gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z
    ];
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      gl.texImage2D(targets[j], 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img[j]);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
      gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

    texture.isloaded = true;

    render(); // Call render function when the image has been loaded (to insure the model is displayed)

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
  }
}
```

The declaration for my different models, it worked just fine and then I started making new ones to apply different textures and for some reason, the program just can't find them anymore.

```js
var sphere, cylinderLight, cylinderDark, box, teapot, disk, torus, cone, fHull, wing, cockpit; // model identifiers
var envbox; // model identifiers


sphere = createModel(uvSphere(10.0, 25.0, 25.0));
box = createModel(cube(1000.0));
fHull = createModel(fHull(), hullTex);
cockpit = createModel(cockpit(), hullTex);
cylinderLight = createModel(uvCylinder(10.0, 20.0, 25.0, false, false), reactorTex);
cylinderDark = createModel(uvCylinder(10.0, 20.0, 25.0, false, true), sReactorTex);
wing = createModel(wing(), wingsTex);
stripes = createModel(wing(), stripesTex);
disk = createModel(ring(2.0, 10.0, 25.0), hullTex);
envbox = createModelbox(cube(1000.0));

teapot = createModel(teapotModel);
torus = createModel(uvTorus(15.0, 5.0, 25.0, 25.0));
cone = createModel(uvCone(10.0, 20.0, 25.0, true));
```

Exemple of a shape (disk) I had to comment out because it kept my ship from fully rendering because of undefined, even though it worked before applying textures. It is only part of a function:

```js
function shipReactors() {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //REACTORS
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //top left BIG
    materialTerms(3, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.3, 4.6, -17.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.13, 0.13, 0.17));
    cylinderLight.render(); //Main
    //top left SMALL
    materialTerms(4, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.5, 4.8, -20.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    cylinderDark.render();
    //Propulsion emitter
    materialTerms(6, 1);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.5, 4.8, -22.2));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    //disk.render();
```

And finally, the createmodel() function, although I doubt this is the problem

```js
function createModel(modelData, texture) {
  var model = {};
  model.coordsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  model.normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  model.textureBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  model.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  model.count = modelData.indices.length;

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.coordsBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, modelData.vertexPositions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.normalBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, modelData.vertexNormals, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.textureBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, modelData.vertexTextureCoords, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  console.log(modelData.vertexPositions.length);
  console.log(modelData.indices.length);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.indexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelData.indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  model.render = function() {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.coordsBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(CoordsLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(NormalLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(TexCoordLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(ModelviewLoc, false, flatten(modelview)); //--- load flattened modelview matrix
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(NormalMatrixLoc, false, flatten(normalMatrix)); //--- load flattened normal matrix

    if (texture.isloaded) {
      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0); //From texture-3cubes.js provided example
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
      // Send texture to sampler
      gl.uniform1i(TextureLoc, 0);
    }

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, this.count, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); //I use TRIANGLE_STRIP to allow more complex shapes to be implemented more easily
  }
  return model;
}

function createModelbox(modelData) { // For creating the environment box.
  var model = {};
  model.coordsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  model.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  model.count = modelData.indices.length;
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.coordsBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, modelData.vertexPositions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  console.log(modelData.vertexPositions.length);
  console.log(modelData.indices.length);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.indexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, modelData.indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  model.render = function() {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.coordsBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aCoordsbox, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uModelviewbox, false, flatten(modelview));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.count, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  }
  return model;
}
```

Thank you in advance, I am aware this is a stretch but I just need some fresh eyes on this.

EDIT: here is the dedicated render function

```js
function render() {
  gl.clearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  projection = perspective(70.0, 1.0, 1.0, 200.0);

  //--- Get the rotation matrix obtained by the displacement of the mouse
  //---  (note: the matrix obtained is already "flattened" by the function getViewMatrix)
  flattenedmodelview = rotator.getViewMatrix();
  modelview = unflatten(flattenedmodelview);

  normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview);

  var initialmodelview = modelview;

  if (texIDmap0.isloaded) { // if texture identifier has been assigned

    var initialmodelview = modelview;

    // Draw the environment (box)
    gl.useProgram(progbox); // Select the shader program that is used for the environment box.

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uProjectionbox, false, flatten(projection));

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aCoordsbox);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(aNormalbox); // normals are not used for the box
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(aTexCoordbox); // texture coordinates not used for the box

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texIDmap0);
    // Send texture to sampler
    gl.uniform1i(uEnvbox, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    envbox.render();

  }
  //  Select shader program 
  gl.useProgram(prog);

  gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "shininess"), materialShininess);
  gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "lightPosition"), flatten(lightPosition));

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(ProjectionLoc, false, flatten(projection)); // send projection matrix to the new shader program

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(CoordsLoc);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(NormalLoc);
  gl.disableVertexAttribArray(TexCoordLoc);

  function shipMain() {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //HULL
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    materialTerms(0, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.7, 0.7, 0.7));
    fHull.render();

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //COCKPIT
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    materialTerms(2, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(0.0, 3.05, -4.5));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-2.0, 1, 0, 0));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.4, 0.6, 0.6));
    cockpit.render();
  }

  function shipWings() {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //WINGS
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    materialTerms(1, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-2.7, 3.0, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-30.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(1, 1, 1));
    wing.render(); //top right
    //Red Stripes re-using wings models
    materialTerms(5, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-2.7, 3.4, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-30.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.9, 0.6, 0.4));
    wing.render(); //top right

    materialTerms(1, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-2.7, 0.0, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(30.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(1, 1, 1));
    wing.render(); //bottom right
    //Red Stripes re-using wings models
    materialTerms(5, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-2.7, -0.4, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(30.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.9, 0.6, 0.4));
    wing.render(); //bot right

    materialTerms(1, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(2.7, 3.0, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-150.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(1, 1, 1));
    wing.render(); //top left
    //Red Stripes re-using wings models
    materialTerms(5, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(2.7, 3.4, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-150.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.9, 0.6, 0.4));
    wing.render(); //top left

    materialTerms(1, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(2.7, 0.0, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(1, 1, 1));
    wing.render(); //bottom left
    //Red Stripes re-using wings models
    materialTerms(5, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(2.7, -0.4, -18.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.9, 0.6, 0.4));
    wing.render(); //bottom left
  }

  function shipReactors() {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //REACTORS
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //top left BIG
    materialTerms(3, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.3, 4.6, -17.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.13, 0.13, 0.17));
    cylinderLight.render(); //Main
    //top left SMALL
    materialTerms(4, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.5, 4.8, -20.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    cylinderDark.render();
    //Propulsion emitter
    materialTerms(6, 1);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.5, 4.8, -22.2));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    //disk.render();

    //bot left
    materialTerms(3, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.3, -2, -17.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.13, 0.13, 0.17));
    cylinderLight.render(); //Main
    //bot left SMALL
    materialTerms(4, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.5, -2.2, -20.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    cylinderDark.render();
    //Propulsion emitter
    materialTerms(6, 1);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(3.5, -2.2, -22.2));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    //disk.render();


    //bot right
    materialTerms(3, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-3.3, -2, -17.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.13, 0.13, 0.17));
    cylinderLight.render(); //Main
    //bot right SMALL
    materialTerms(4, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-3.5, -2.2, -20.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    cylinderDark.render();
    //Propulsion emitter
    materialTerms(6, 1);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-3.5, -2.2, -22.2));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    //disk.render();

    //top right
    materialTerms(3, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-3.3, 4.6, -17.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.13, 0.13, 0.17));
    cylinderLight.render(); //Main
    //top right SMALL
    materialTerms(4, 0);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-3.5, 4.8, -20.0));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    cylinderDark.render();
    //Propulsion emitter
    materialTerms(6, 1);
    modelview = initialmodelview;
    modelview = mult(modelview, translate(-3.5, 4.8, -22.2));
    modelview = mult(modelview, rotate(-210.0, 0, 0, 1));
    normalMatrix = extractNormalMatrix(modelview); // always extract the normal matrix before scaling
    modelview = mult(modelview, scale(0.07, 0.07, 0.21));
    //disk.render();
  }

  shipMain(); //Originally created to fix an undefined function bug, but I kept it to make the code more flexible
  shipWings();
  shipReactors();

}
```

Comment: I cant seem to find any dedicated render function in the extensive code snippets you posted? If you're trying to call `model.render` in your texture callbacks you need to call it on your model instance.

Comment: It is extensive, and there is a lot more haha. I didnt want to flood the page, but I added it. For example, my application will draw the ship until it gets to the first disk.render(). For some reason it returns as undefined even though it is declared in the same way as all the other models.

Comment: I guess my question is very broad, so lets just say this: have you guys ever experienced a function being undefined in WebGL or js when it apparently is? If so, what are the common mistakes on this subject? I am a .js noob so there might be functionalities or behaviors i'm not aware of.

Comment: Are you defining functions inside your functions just to call them later on ... ? Usually those problems track back to wrong scoping, for instance defining the `render` function inside a document ready callback. To counteract this you could define it like this `window.render = function () {}`. Still you may should take a step back and study some open source javascript projects and their code structure. Maybe use a library to handle the abstraction for you.

Comment: Thank you I will keep looking, I am sure you are right. The scoping is all over the place.

Comment: I can't see when your "handleLoadedTexture" functions are called but are you sure that these functions are called after all code is loaded? If you add your declaration of render later and the code can already execute before it loaded the render function it would not find it. For a test you could put the declaration of render right before handleLoadedTexture.